# Why three pair matched keypoints in four cannot be colinear when computing homographies?

Tags: computer-vision, homography

Suppose extracting four keypoints from a real 3-d plane so that I can compute homograph matrix from 8 constraints.
  I cannot understand: why three pair keypoints in four cannot be collinear when computing homographies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, the homography maps a quadrilateral into another quadrilateral. If three points are collinear the quad is degenerate.